# Using Regex in :contains jQuery Selector

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I am trying to use regex in a `:contains` jQuery selector and I am having issues finding documentation that supports being able to do so. I have the `DOM` of a webpage loaded in the `domContent` variable and trying to find all lines that contain a webURL and log it to the console. I just want to output all instances of an email address listed in the `DOM`.

```
function doStuffWithDOM(domContent) {
      console.log($(domContent).filter(":contains('@')").text())
}
```

I want to replace the `@` with a regex that outputs an email address based on the following regex `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b`

Comment: Keep in mind that if a user enter a wrong address it's his problem, not yours. The only important thing is the confirmation email. So only checking the @ is present looks a reasonable compromise (when a regex will exclude many correct addresses).

Comment: *"I am having issues finding documentation that supports being able to do so"*: that's because there is no such documentation. Why did you think regexes were possible in `:contains`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a regular expression using the `:contains()` selector.

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/), nowhere does it say a regex can be used, and the parameter `text` is just a plain string text:

> text: A string of text to look for. It's case sensitive.

What you're looking for is using the filter's [function parameter](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function):

[image: screenshot of function signature in documentation]

This allows you to write custom code in the function (which can include a regular expression), and return `true` for elements that match the expression.

For more information, see "**Using a Filter Function**" section in the [linked documentation](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function).